# Find the maximum distance that cross an edge - Matlab

Tags: matlab, distance

I'm pretty sure that the title isn't clear enough. I'll try to explain: 
 I have a lot of surfaces that I have to compare to another (fixed one). The surfaces are defined by a 10x18xN matrix, being N the number of surfaces. 
 What I want to compare is if any point of any N surface exceeds the fixed surface and calculate the distance that it exceeds. 
 I'm comparing point-by-point, like this:

```
  for j = 1 : N
     for i = 1 : 10
        for k = 1 : 18
            if surface(i,k,j) > surface_fixed(i,k)
                 dist = surface(i,k,j) - surface_fixed(i,k)
            end
        end
     end
   end
```

But I want to know if it is possible to calculate this "dist" (distance) without being point-by-point, because it takes me too much time !

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how you define  `surface(i,j,k)` exceeds `surface_fixed(i,k)` ?

Comment: I feel your indexing is incorrect. Shouldn't it be surface(i,k,j) since your stack of edges has been defined as 10X18XN?. I'll try and explain what I understand so that you may correct me if I'm mistaken.

If my understanding is correct, how can the pixel difference between stacked indices be defined as distance?

You have multiple matrices which are 10 X 18 in nature and you have stacked them one after the other to produce a 10 X 18 X N matrix. I am assuming each matrix has a large number to signify an edge while the non 'edge' regions are comparatively small numbers?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I corrected it.
I can calculate distances because it has some values in this 10x18 matrix. These values are the Z (height) of the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's assume a few things here:

'Surface' is a variable which is the depth map (the Z component as you said earlier). 'Surface_fixed' is what you are comparing it with. 'Surface' is 10 X 18 X N matrix and 'Surface_fixed' is 10 X 18.

Try the following and let me know if this is what you need:

```
    Dist_measures = zeros(10,18,N);
    for i = 1:N
        Dist_measures(:,:,i) = Surface(:,:,i) - Surface_fixed;
    end
```

Dist_measures will hold the difference in heights. You give a threshold to it such that you get the [x , y] location for every index different from your fixed surface.

[x , y] = find(abs(Dist_measures(i)) > Thres)

here you may iterate through i and get the [x , y] coordinates of any location of a PARTICULAR surface.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tested like you said and it worked fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"But I want to know if it is possible to calculate this "dist" (distance) without being point-by-point, because it takes me too much time !"

Then you likely want to vectorise this. It is independent of `j`according to your construct so something like:

> dist = surface(:,:,1) - surface_fixed;

However, I feel more details are needed as your indexing may be incorrect. You could try something like:

> dist = surface - reshape(repmat(surface_fixed,size(surface,1),size(surface))

but without more details on what you're doing I have fairly high credent that that is not what you're after (and may create large arrays unneccessaryily)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm going to test it ASAP and then post here more details if it's needed